# Change Default Search Scope in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

The default search scope is always 'Entire Solution' which just BEGS for the end user, at some point, to exercise the option in Source Control to undo pending changes. :)

Is there a way to have a blank in this drop down or custom set it to Current Document?

Personally, why invite disaster as the first option?  Let's have the Nuclear Option as one that must be intentionally selected, not just set it as the default.

It's obviously not because of an alpha setting, since Current Document should come up first if that were the case, which means someone decided this was the best default, maybe the guiding thought is 'Let's just see who's not on their toes today.'

Enough of a rant ... if there is a setting to force Alpha Order, that solves the issue.  If it can be customized, even better.

Thanks!